# Get Isometric Tile Under Mouse

Tags: java, mouse, iso, tile, isometric

Ok, so I have my isometric map where the width of each tile is 64 and the height is 32.
This is the equation I came up with to place the tiles

```
xPos = (this.getPos().getX() - this.getPos().getY()) * (64 / 2) - Main.gameWindow.getCamera().getxOffset().intValue();
xPos -= 32;
yPos = (this.getPos().getX() + this.getPos().getY()) * (32 / 2) - Main.gameWindow.getCamera().getyOffset().intValue();
```

I subtract xPos by 32 to make up for the fact that the origin point of the tile is in the far left corner.

What I've been trying to do is find the tile that is beneath my mouse.
So first I tried simply reversing the equation (I was sure it would work)
And this is the code I ended up with when I reversed it.

```
int yMouseTile = ( (cursorY / (32 / 2) - (cursorX / 32)) / 2 );
int xMouseTile = ( (cursorX / 32) + yMouseTile);
```

This only sort of works. But as it turns out, this code actually treats each tile as if it were a square, not a diamond.

The next weird part is that when my mouse passes over the center of the tile, the tile changes. So what should happen, is that my mouse should go over the edge of the tile, and then it changes to the next one. But instead, it acts as if the center of tile is actually the edge.

But really, all I want is the equation that will cause my mouse to work like this
http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut18.html

On that link, click the "Click Here to Start" Button, and watch how the mouse interacts with the tiles. That is my goal :), thanks

P.S. I've tried a myriad of different equations, many of which have the exact same result as the equation I have above

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your variable names.

```
int TILE_WIDTH = 64;
int TILE_HEIGHT = TILE_WIDTH / 2;

int xMap = this.getPos().getX();
int yMap = this.getPos().getY();

int xScreenCameraOffset = Main.gameWindow.getCamera().getxOffset().intValue();
int yScreenCameraOffset = Main.gameWindow.getCamera().getyOffset().intValue();

xScreen = (xMap - yMap) * (TILE_WIDTH / 2) - yScreenCameraOffset;
yScreen = (xMap + yMap) * (TILE_HEIGHT / 2) - yScreenCameraOffset;
```

This might seem excessive, but in my opinion is way easier to read and reason about. According to [this tutorial](http://clintbellanger.net/articles/isometric_math/) If you try to derive The reverse equation you would get:

```
xMouseTile = (xCursor / TILE_WIDTH  / 2 + yCursor / TILE_HEIGHT / 2) / 2;
yMouseTile = (yCursor / TILE_HEIGHT / 2 - xCursor / TILE_WIDTH  / 2) / 2;
```

This doesn't take into account the camera offset.

Comment: I've actually tried that tutorial (although I used that tutorial's more condensed version of that code). And it yielded the same results, any idea why?

Comment: So basically, by using the tutorial you just sent me, and using his finished code, this is what the result looks like http://gyazo.com/1387cfe7472b816f6009292e8f0df4c3

Comment: Is it always one tile off on the x (tile) axis? Is there anything else wrong with it?

Comment: In that pic, if I were to move my mouse past the center point of the tile my mouse is on, then it would move over the correct tile. So yes.

I've tried offsetting it so that instead of the center of the tile, it's on the edge of the tile. And the worked somewhat, except that it only works perfectly if my mouse were in the center of the edge of said tile, if you get what I'm saying.

Basically it is acting as if the bounding box of each tile is a rectangle, not a diamond